# Should the [piano] tag be burninated?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

In no way is a [piano](/questions/tagged/piano) relevant to programming (except in a [twisted, musical way](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-one-thing-programmers-and-musicians-have-in-common.html)), so I propose its burnination.  Agree?  Disagree?

Comment: Yep... just removed it from some questions.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian: [Apparently you can also "sing" a form...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015964/signing-an-iframe-form-to-validate-its-sender)

Comment: When I read over this 9 months later, I tell myself: In no way possible did I make this question... hacker or magic, I am not this good.

Comment: When I read over that comment 2 years later, I tell myself: In no way possible did I make that comment... hacked or magic, I was not that immature...

Answer (score 10):

Definitely agree. There are some other related tags that, imho, should be considered for burnination as well:

- [chord](/questions/tagged/chord)
- [guitar](/questions/tagged/guitar)
- [note](/questions/tagged/note)
- [singing](/questions/tagged/singing)
- [playback](/questions/tagged/playback)
- [mixer](/questions/tagged/mixer)

Comment: "mixer" could well be legitimate (e.g., for questions about the [Windows audio mixer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756706.aspx)). Although it's somewhat vague, "playback" might be at least semi-legitimate as well).

Comment: There seems to be a legit use of "chord" tag, used in [here as Chord network](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21289420/remote-write-consistency-protocol-in-distributed-systems), but I think it's still too localized.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian [dogfooding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eating_your_own_dog_food) is a well known term in some circles of software engineering.